# Push predefined objects into array using setState in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, immutability, setstate

How can I achieve this using the spread operator/ES6?

I want to loop through my data and populate my state with an array of objects where the objects contain two key/value pairs. I would like it to be like...

```
this.state = {
data: [ {indexNumber: 1, show: false}, {indexNumber: 2, show: false}, {indexNumber: 3, show: false} ]
```

My [mutated] version;

```
this.state = { data: []}

data.map((element, index) => {
    this.state.data.push({ indexNumber: index, show: false}] })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify the state object. You will have to call setState and use a new value:

`this.setState({data: [...this.state.data, {indexNumber: index, show: false}]})`